# Keymapping different between Python2.4 and Python2.7 on RedHat

Tags: python, python-2.7, redhat, python-2.4

I am running SLC5 (RedHat 4 Linux). The distributed Python version is 2.4. I have installed Python 2.7 in addition manually (altinstall).

Running in terminal mode (Runlevel 3), the key mapping in bash and the Python 2.4 interpreter are correct (backspace, key arrows, etc. are working fine). When running the Python 2.7 interpreter, the key mappings are wrong (Backspace = ^? instead of ^H; Ctrl-H is working fine)

When running under gnome (Runlevel 5) in the gnome-terminal, the mapping is correct for Python 2.7.

Any idea what I need to set/configure that the key mapping is correct for Python 2.7 in the terminal mode (RL3) ?

Thanks very much !

Markus

Comment: Hunch: no readline support compiled. Have you got libreadline-dev or equivalent installed?

Answer (score -1):

This page describes the **main key** differences between Python 2.4 and Python 2.7:

- Multithreading

Python 2.4 : Not available.

Python 2.7: You can use the Python 2.7 threading library. All threads in a request must finish before the request deadline (60 seconds for online requests and 10 minutes for offline).

- Concurrent requests

Python 2.4 : Not supported.

Python 2.7 :Can use concurrent requests as long as you specify the threadsafe directive in app.yaml. Script handlers must use the Python WSGI interface in order to be threadsafe.
In backends, raising an exception from a shutdown hook copies that exception to all threads.

- Bytecode upload

Python 2.4: Not available.

Python 2.7: Can upload .pyc files, but not in combination with .py files. However, you can upload .zip files containing .py or .pyc files (or a combination).

- Preferred interface (WSGI vs. CGI)
  Python 2.4: CGI is the only supported interface.

Python 2.7: WSGI is the preferred interface, and is required for multithreading. For more information about converting CGI handlers to WSGI, see Migrating to Python 2.7.

- Support for C modules

Python 2.4: Some C modules are not available. See the libraries knowledge base for more information.

Python 2.7: The following C modules are not available: 
ctypes, sqlite, ssl, _ssl, fcntl, spwd, pwd, grp, syslog, select, _socket